# Change svg file color on hover

Tags: css, svg, filter, colors, hover

I'm working on a [frontendmentor](https://frontendmentor.io) challenge, and it came with a few svg files to use in the footer, and the last thing I need to do is make those svgs change color when you hover over them. Typically, I'd use `filter:hue-rotate()` but that only seems to work on some of the svg files, but not others.

For instance, if I have this html:

```
<footer>
  <img src="./images/logo.svg">
  <img src="./images/icon-facebook.svg">
</footer>
```

... and this CSS:

```
footer img {
  filter:hue-rotate(90deg);
}
```

.. then the logo image gets color shifted but the facebook image does not. I'm able to view the contents of the svg images in VSCode, and they are a bit different, as the logo has a few components, while the facebook logo is much simpler. Here's the contents:

logo.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="139" height="20">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="a" x1="72.195%" x2="17.503%" y1="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#33D35E" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#2AB6D9" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <path fill="#2D314D" fill-rule="nonzero"
      d="M37.754 15.847c2.852 0 5.152-1.622 5.952-4.216h-3.897c-.376.665-1.14 1.066-2.055 1.066-1.237 0-2.065-.674-2.32-1.978h8.44c.051-.352.081-.694.081-1.037 0-3.335-2.537-5.95-6.201-5.95-3.568 0-6.175 2.564-6.175 6.049 0 3.473 2.628 6.066 6.175 6.066zm2.344-7.297h-4.596c.317-1.129 1.11-1.749 2.252-1.749 1.181 0 2 .613 2.344 1.75zm10.946 7.296c1.32 0 2.5-.434 3.43-1.188l.336.804h3.027V4.093h-2.919l-.4.88c-.94-.775-2.135-1.222-3.474-1.222-3.476 0-5.961 2.505-5.961 6.026 0 3.533 2.485 6.07 5.961 6.07zm.524-3.467c-1.467 0-2.545-1.108-2.545-2.593 0-1.475 1.069-2.583 2.545-2.583 1.466 0 2.544 1.108 2.544 2.583 0 1.485-1.078 2.593-2.544 2.593zm13.123 3.467c3.02 0 5.025-1.554 5.025-3.93 0-2.883-2.387-3.256-4.183-3.575-1.08-.193-1.95-.344-1.95-.99 0-.527.422-.838 1.05-.838.71 0 1.197.337 1.197 1.063h3.667c-.044-2.303-1.92-3.843-4.816-3.843-2.912 0-4.854 1.47-4.854 3.75 0 2.757 2.337 3.289 4.1 3.574 1.092.181 1.952.368 1.952 1.024 0 .587-.543.88-1.116.88-.742 0-1.32-.383-1.32-1.214h-3.77c.036 2.463 1.919 4.1 5.018 4.1zm8.1 3.858c2.936 0 4.344-1.257 5.877-4.736l4.764-10.863h-4.206l-2.249 6.263-2.412-6.263H70.31l4.698 10.43c-.53 1.414-.983 1.804-2.48 1.804H71.45v3.365h1.341zm18.504-3.858c3.5 0 5.973-2.515 5.973-6.048S94.796 3.75 91.295 3.75a5.332 5.332 0 00-2.825.784V0H84.6v15.474h2.897l.37-.844c.923.771 2.102 1.216 3.428 1.216zm-.523-3.467c-1.467 0-2.545-1.108-2.545-2.58 0-1.486 1.078-2.594 2.545-2.594 1.466 0 2.544 1.108 2.544 2.593 0 1.473-1.087 2.58-2.544 2.58zm13.598 3.467c1.32 0 2.5-.434 3.43-1.188l.336.804h3.027V4.093h-2.918l-.401.88c-.939-.775-2.135-1.222-3.474-1.222-3.476 0-5.96 2.505-5.96 6.026 0 3.533 2.484 6.07 5.96 6.07zm.524-3.467c-1.467 0-2.545-1.108-2.545-2.593 0-1.475 1.07-2.583 2.545-2.583 1.467 0 2.545 1.108 2.545 2.583 0 1.485-1.078 2.593-2.545 2.593zm12.653 3.095V9.403c0-1.447.702-2.3 1.923-2.3.986 0 1.483.657 1.483 1.98v6.39h3.915V8.543c0-2.897-1.733-4.773-4.373-4.773-1.47 0-2.733.565-3.58 1.508l-.537-1.172h-2.747v11.369h3.916zm13.748 0v-4.808l2.848 4.808h4.616l-3.902-5.95 3.543-5.419h-4.397l-2.708 4.454V0h-3.916v15.474h3.916z" />
    <g fill="url(#a)">
      <path d="M10.802 0L0 19.704h5.986L16.789 0z" />
      <path opacity=".5" d="M18.171 0L7.368 19.704h5.986L24.157 0z" />
      <path opacity=".15" d="M25.539 0L14.737 19.704h5.986L31.525 0z" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

icon-facebook.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20">
  <path fill="#FFF"
    d="M18.896 0H1.104C.494 0 0 .494 0 1.104v17.793C0 19.506.494 20 1.104 20h9.58v-7.745H8.076V9.237h2.606V7.01c0-2.583 1.578-3.99 3.883-3.99 1.104 0 2.052.082 2.329.119v2.7h-1.598c-1.254 0-1.496.597-1.496 1.47v1.928h2.989l-.39 3.018h-2.6V20h5.098c.608 0 1.102-.494 1.102-1.104V1.104C20 .494 19.506 0 18.896 0z" />
</svg>
```

So the question is, what's the technical difference in why logo can utilize css filters but facebook cannot? And ultimately, what's the solution here to make the facebook logo change colors when hovered? Using `fill:#f00` doesn't seem to work either as I can't target the inner svg components since its a file.

Note: I could create a 2nd image and color it differently and swap between them, or I could extract the inner svg stuff and insert that into the page instead, but I'm really trying to understand/solve the .svg file problem. Or at least verify 100% that it **can't** be done.

Note2: StackOverflow showed me another similar question (*similar*, but **NOT THE SAME**), and the answer there was that you can't affect svg file color/fill with CSS only inline SVG elements. Ok, noted, but what about CSS filters? They seem to work on the logo image but not the Facebook image, so why is that? What's the main thing there that's causing it work on one but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

When I use this in my css, I can make the facebook logo any color I want:

```
footer img:hover {
  background-color: *Any color you want it to be*;
}
```

But the point is, this works well for the Facebook logo but not for the first logo..

Comment: This only changes the background color, but leaves the main image color (white). Set your footer to have a dark background and you'll see what I mean. I want to do the opposite, I don't need to change the background color, I want to shift the color of the main image instead, which is why I wanted to use filter:hue-rotate()...

Comment: I looked for it but I'm afraid you have to use change the code in your svg files. Use fill and stroke.